# change font size in caption for selected figures

Tags: captions, fontsize, exercises

I am trying to have some environments in my LaTeX document where the font in general is smaller than in the main text. This means that whenever I include a figure, the caption from the `\begin{figure}...` should have the same (smaller) font size. I found answers where the change is globally by providing the font size parameter to the caption package. Yet I was wondering if I could do this locally for some figures. Actually, I would like to know if this is possible in the definition of the exercise environment I have:

```
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise} % for exercise environment

% set font for exercise environment
\newcommand\ExerciseFont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\AtBeginAnswer{\ExerciseFont}
\renewcommand\AtBeginExercise{\ExerciseFont}

% change format of exercise environment
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\ExerciseFont\textsc{
                \ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB. \ExerciseHeaderTitle
                \ExerciseHeaderOrigin}}

% change font for answers header
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\ExerciseFont\textit{
                Solution:\ }}
```

Can I somehow change the font size for the figures in such environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an `\ExerciseCaption` to use within the exercise. By using `\captionsetup` in `caption.sty` the caption can be changed locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\ExerciseCaption[1]{%
  \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}%
  \caption{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Test 1}
  \label{TA}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}
  \ExerciseCaption{Test 2}
  \label{TB}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{TA} and Figure \ref{TB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm getting a `Missing \endcsname inserted.` error. Do you know why?

Comment: I cannot get the same error here. I have tried to include also the `exercise`package together with your settings, and a figure within an exercise. But it compiles as expected. Maybe you have some other included packages?

Comment: I have a lot of included packages. I'm using the `subcaption` package actually. Any ideas on how I can determine the source of the conflict?

Comment: I think `subcaption`is part of `caption` so that should work. I would start with your original (compilable) document and just add `\usepackage{caption}`. If that works add `\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}` just before a caption. If that works it is only the command left.

Comment: If `subcaption`is loaded separately with options, there might be a clash with the options to `caption`?

Comment: I did as you suggested, and added `\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}` before the caption and it worked! The command you provide gives me that error.

Comment: Now it works! The problem was that inside that command I was using  `\ExerciseFont` instead of `footnotesize`, which I defined earlier as `\newcommand\ExerciseFont{\footnotesize}`. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: The `footnotesize`is an input parameter to `caption`, telling it to use `\footnotesize`. How that is internally handled is something else, and you can only give the per-specified inputs.